# How to link third party dll from class library in Xamarin.iOS when using VS2012 and Build Host

Tags: c#, ios, json, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I making a small cross platform project, and wan't my webservice calls, in a separate class library project. I've created a Xamarin.iOS solution, and added a class library, which is referenced from the application. In the class library, I've defined a simple webservice class that calls a webservice and deserializes the json into a POCO using Newtonsoft.Json. The problem is that because Newtonsoft.Json is referenced from the class library and not the application, the Newtonsoft.Json.dll file is not linked into the application - only the class library dll - and I get a file-not-found when deserializing.
I tried to use --linkskip=Newtonsoft.Json in the application but that doesn't help.

How do I force the buildhost to link that dll into the application?

Comment: Your library is a Portable Class Library? What level of linking is set in your build options, Link all Assemblies? Did you reference the Portable version of Newtonsoft.Json?

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back.
It's not a PCL, just a ios class library added to the main solution. I've tried all possible values for the linker, without luck. I'm referencing the json.net from the Component store, but I don't think it's the dll version that is the problem - it's just the linker that removes it.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution. Since the linker don't care to embed the newtonsoft.json.dll in the solution, I add the file to the class library, besides referencing the one in the Component folder. That seems to work. No more "missing file"